# How to get the count of number of times the app launch iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im developing a reminder app.

So my client want to set a rate this application popup message, that'll come up on the 10th time user open the app.is this possible.

How can i implement this?

Can anyone help me please.Thanks in advance

Comment: Heart-full thanks to all who respond to this question.All of your questions are correct.Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use NSUserDefaults for this:

```
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger appLaunchAmounts = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"LaunchAmounts"];
    if (appLaunchAmounts == 10)
    {
        [self showMessage];
    }
    [userDefaults setInteger:appLaunchAmounts+1 forKey:@"LaunchAmounts"];
```

Comment: in did finish lauch or  (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application?

Comment: @user923370 applicationDidFinishLaunching:

Answer (score 5):

You can store that into the `NSUserDefaults`. Just update it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Answer (score 4):

You can save an integer in `NSUserDefaults`

```
- (void)setInteger:(NSInteger)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

Retrieve it and increment it every time the appDidFinishLaunching (or appWillEnterForeground) delegate methods is called. Probably best to use appWillEnterForeground as sometimes apps can lie in the background unterminated for days.

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger count = [defaults integerForKey:@"LaunchCount"];
count++;
/* Do checks and review prompt */
[defaults setInteger:count forKey:@"LaunchCount"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will store a value in NSUserDefaults called 'AppLaunchCount'.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"AppLaunchCount"])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"AppLaunchCount"] + 1) forKey:@"AppLaunchCount"];
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"AppLaunchCount"];
}
}
```